# Stripe Webhooks StripeSignatureVerificationError

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, stripe-payments, backend

I'm currently testing the **Stripe** **Webhook** Endpoints for the **Checkout** Process.

I'm confused because Stripe shows two different snippets how to set up the Webhook endpoint in their docs.

In the [Checkout Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment) they show this code snippet:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

// Find your endpoint's secret in your Dashboard's webhook settings
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_...';

// Using Express
const app = require('express')();

// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Match the raw body to content type application/json
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object;

    // Fulfill the purchase...
    handleCheckoutSession(session);
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Running on port 8000'));
```

And in their [Webhook Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build) they are showing this snippet:

```
const app = require('express')();
// Use body-parser to retrieve the raw body as a buffer
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Match the raw body to content type application/json
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  let event;

  try {
    event = JSON.parse(request.body);
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
      // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
      break;
    case 'payment_method.attached':
      const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
      // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
      // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
      break;
    // ... handle other event types
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return response.status(400).end();
  }
  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.json({received: true});
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Running on port 8000'));
```

I tried both snippets but nothing seems to work for me.

The first one gives me the **StripeSignatureVerificationError** when I try to constructEvent(...)

and the second one is telling me that the Object **event**  is **undefined**.

Does someone know why both of these endpoints are not working for me ?

Comment: Error message of the first snippet is :" No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?"

Comment: Go with the first snippet for now. If you log `request.body` before calling constructEvent, does it match exactly the event shown on the Stripe dashboard, including whitespace? Is your endpointSecret correct — does it match exactly the secret from your dashboard/emitted by stripe-cli?

Answer (score 4):

Before using JSON Body parser configure to receive RAW body

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: "*/*"}))  <-- This line need to be added
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

More discussion https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/331